# Qt- how to run two slots simultaneously without explicitly implementing threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, qt

I have two Qt slots that are connected to the same signal.

I must run them in parallel without explicitly using Qt multi-threading.

I searched if Qt has provided a solution to do that impliciltly, But I did not find.

is there any solution to do that in Qt?

Comment: nope. Parallel = multithreading. If you have no multithreading then you cannot do things in parallel.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. Run them in parallel without running them in parallel? Besides, even _with_ threads you can't guarantee they actually run in parallel. What if you're on a single-threaded CPU, or if the OS assigns only a single core to your program?

Comment: @MSalters: You can write a complete answer, I will tick it and upvote it. The problem may be confronted by many Qt users.

Comment: As was mentioned above you can't run anything in parallel without multithreading. If by "without using multi-threading" you mean "each slot in separate threads but without using and subclassing QThread" there is a very simple solution

Comment: @BeardedBeaver: yes this is what I want. I reedeited the question

Comment: Qt Concurrent namespace provides high level API to make multi-threaded programs without using explicitly QThread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect your signal to `slot()` and use `QtConurrent` to do all work

```
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QFuture>
...
void MyClass::slot()
{
    QFuture <void> future1, future2;
    future1 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MyClass::slot1);
    future2 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MyClass::slot2);
    future1.waitForFinished();
    future2.waitForFinished();
}
```

You need to use the concurrent module. In the `.pro` file, add:

```
QT += concurrent
```

Comment: Variation: Just have two slots, and one `QtConcurrent::run` call of `slot2` at the start of  `slot1`. Then do the normal work of `slot1`, and at the end of `slot1` you call `waitForFinished` on the future of `slot2`.